# Counting the number of words in a string in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, string, loops

> ```
> public static int countWords(String str)
> ```
>
> This method will count the number of words in str 
>   For example, if `str = "Hi there"`, the method would return 2.

I'm a beginner and not supposed to use pre-built programs. I know it probably uses a loop and I need to use `.indexOf` to find spaces? Something like my failed attempt at the bottom

```
public static int countWords(String str){
    int count=0;
    int len=str.length();
    if(str.indexOf(" ")>=0){
     for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        count=count+i;
    }
    return count;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-built programs"? Can you use Scanner class, or are you limited to only methods from String class?

Comment: @Pshemo I mean things like some of the answers below: .trim, .split, parts, .isEmpty(). We also haven't learned about NULL so I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
public static int countWords(String str){
   if(str == null){
    return 0;  // or your wish to return something
   }
   str = str.trim();
   return str.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Where `\\s+` will split the string even there are around spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation is completely wrong:

- If the string doesn't contain a space, it will not enter the `if` block, and incorrectly return 0, because that's the initial value of `count` and it was never changed
- If the string contains a space, the loop does not what you want: it sums up the numbers from 0 to `len`, for example if `len = 5`, the result will be `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4`
- There's nothing in the code to account for *words*. Note that counting the spaces would not be enough, for example consider the input: "   Hello   there   :-)   ". Notice the excessive spaces between words, and also at the start and end, and the non-word smiley.

This should be relatively robust:

```
int countWords(String text) {
    String[] parts = text.trim().split("\\W+");
    if (parts.length == 1 && parts[0].isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return parts.length;
}
```

The tedious `if` condition there is to handle some special cases:

- empty string
- string with only non-word characters

Unit tests:

```
@Test
public void simple() {
    assertEquals(4, countWords("this is a test"));
}

@Test
public void empty() {
    assertEquals(0, countWords(""));
}

@Test
public void only_non_words() {
    assertEquals(0, countWords("@#$#%"));
}

@Test
public void with_extra_spaces() {
    assertEquals(4, countWords("  this is   a   test  "));
}

@Test
public void with_non_words() {
    assertEquals(4, countWords("  this is   a   test  :-) "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountWordsInString {
    public static int countWords(String string) {
        String[] strArray = string.split(" ");
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : strArray) {
            if (!s.equals("")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter your string: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Total Words: " + countWords(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.